# "Непримиримые друг к другу" - можно? Книжный прецедент найден

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

У меня:

> И то напряжение, которое было разлито сейчас по улице, и те
>   **непримиримые друг к другу** правды, которые вставали сейчас за каждым из участников и расправляли свои знамена…

В найденной книге:

[В Шекспире соединились непримиримые друг к другу Брехт и Беккет.](https://books.google.ru/books?id=97_8AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%20%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83&source=bl&ots=tW67I0HIro&sig=K1CfBNFLFVh7zTOdw1iiL1MNhIQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8voiTiqfaAhXHKewKHbkID3EQ6AEIRDAJ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%20%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83&f=false)

Ещё:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _Galina Avanesova: “Непримиримые друг к другу” - можно?_ === Галина, возможно, я что-то пропустил в более ранних обсуждениях... По-моему, “непримиримые друг к другу” – совершенно нормальное сочетание. Почему у Вас такой вопрос-то сейчас возник?

Comment: См. примеры: https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3+%D0%BA+%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%22&newwindow=1&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMyNzUzKfaAhUFjiwKHZ6EB0oQ_AUIECgB&biw=1280&bih=601 ======= https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B+%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3+%D0%BA+%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%22&newwindow=1&dcr=0&tbm=bks&ei=5m3IWprdFYOpsgH517zICA&start=10&sa=N&biw=1280&bih=601&dpr=1

Comment: Слава, спасибо! Вы ничего не пропустили, это я глупая тетеря. Что-то мне резануло слух; я так не говорю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если абстрактно о сочетании. Примеры в вопросе - из *переводов* (последний пример отпадает: "ненависть друг к другу" + "непримиримая ненависть"). Вариант "**друг с другом**" (*примиряться с чем/кем* - логично для производного слова сохранять подобное управление: *ничто не могло их примирить друг с другом*) чаще находится в изначально русскоязычных книжках (по смыслу это о взаимоотношениях людей, знакомых лично). Оправдать исходный вариант тоже можно, притянув его по управлению к более ясному "непримиримо относившиеся друг к другу" (это об отношении каждого в отдельности к другому; они могут при этом и не встречаться).

О "правдах" и вовсе нужно **одна с другой**.